# Add class to element with ONLY a child element

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I would liek to use jquery to find every single instance of a strong tag within a p tag, and add a class to the p tag like so:

```
<p><strong>Bold Text</strong></p>
```

will become

```
<p class="hasStrong"><strong>Bold Text</strong></p>
```

Im not sure the best way to accomplish this, here is a shot:

```
$("p").find("strong").parent("p").addClass("hasStrong");
```

This works, but I want it to select paragraphs that ONLY have a strong tag, and nothing else. SO this would not have the class applied:

```
<p><strong>Bold Text</strong> Here is some more text</p>
```

How would I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('p:has(strong)').filter(function(){
    return $(this).contents().length === 1;
}).addClass('hasStrong');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vbzkt/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('p').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() == $(this).find('strong').text();
}).addClass('yourclass');
```

Comment: This might be the first solution with some merit. It seems to be comparing the contents of the <p> with the contents of the <strong> to see if they match.

Comment: this seems like a great idea and might be more lightweight then @Explosion's answer

Comment: If there is whitespace around the `<strong>` tag, the `.text()` values will be different but the DOM won't perceive the whitespace. If this is an issue, then `$.trim()`ing both strings will resolve it.

Comment: I think that this solution is great, but it is imperfect because `.text` on the strong collection will return all of the text concatenated together, which throws a wrench in everything.  It also doesn't account for empty elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/XMrRs/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to select text nodes with jQuery.  This would be much easier if you didn't need to do that.

You can still do it, though, by using `.contents` to check text node length as well.

```
$("p").find("strong:only-child").each(function () {
    var $p = $(this).closest('p');
    if ($p.contents().length === 1) {
        $p.addClass('hasStrong');
    }
});
```

The `:only-child` works perfectly for filtering out only eligible nodes to begin with, but is not strictly necessray.  Note that this also highlights `<strong>` that contain children.  If you don't want to do that, just check that `$(this)` has no children in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Selects only `p` tags that have one or more `strong` tags, and no textnodes:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $('strong', this).length == this.childNodes.length;
}).addClass('hasStrong');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4A2Z/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that takes text nodes into consideration:

```
$("p").filter( function() {
    return this.childNodes.length === 1 && $( 'strong', this ).length;
} ).addClass("hasStrong");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vDfV5/

Comment: why -1? this also seems like a solid solution

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by drilling down then using "parent()" to add the class to the strongs parent.

$("p").children("strong").parent().addClass("hasStrong");